# How to have a full width resize of html pages ? Just the body, main content, not everything

Tags: html, css, viewport

I don't remember but I heard there is a way to resize the main width of Html web pages.

I just want to have a resize on the body/ main content of the page (width and height could be on auto). Not every tag. It's for the mobile website version. 
If I remember it's in the head.

Do I have to not have fixed width in CSS ? Or it could be only with % ? 
Codes would be really appreciated!

Comment: Media-queries may help you.

Comment: Yes, i know Media Queries a bit. But the boss just want a complete resize on the general aspect of the web pages. Like everything in small to fit on a mobile screen and put it scalable.

Comment: So you want it to fill the whole screen and they can pinch zoom?

Comment: Hi hungerstar, yes, it's exactly that. Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a meta tag like this one in your `<head>` to start with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

That alone won't do the re-sizing for you. You'll likely want to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to control the width of your pages. Below is a very simple *mobile first* approach.

```css
/* Default styles here (small screens) */

@media ( min-width: 720px ) {
   .content {
       width: 720px;
   }
}
@media ( min-width: 940px ) {
   .content {
       width: 940px;
   }
}
@media ( min-width: 1140px ) {
   .content {
       width: 1140px;
   }
}
```

As far as the suggestion of only re-sizing certain elements on the page, some will want to re-flow on their own depending on if they're `inline`, `inline-block` or if you have floated them. In some situations you'll likely have to re-size said elements as they will not render in a usable satisfactory way at certain screen sizes.

I don't see a lot of fixed width these days unless it's for a containing element like my example above. Though if you need to use fixed with you'd want to use them with media queries for the max amount of control when targeting different screen sizes.

```html
<div class="content">
    <main class="main">Main</main>
    <aside class="sidebar">Sidebar</aside>
</div>
```

```css
/* all screens 479px wide and below */
.main,
.sidebar {
    width: 100%;
}
/* all screens 480px wide and above until you hit 720px */
@media ( min-width: 480px ) {
    .main {
        width: 300px;
    }
    .sidebar {
        width: 180px;
    }
 }
/* all screens 720px wide and above */
@media ( min-width: 720px ) {
    .main {
        width: 450px;
    }
    .sidebar {
        width: 270px;
    }
 }
```

Otherwise I suggest a route you'll often see, which is using percentage widths inside a fixed width container.

```html
<div class="content">
    <main class="main">Main</main>
    <aside class="sidebar">Sidebar</aside>
</div>
```

```css
/* all screens 719px wide and below */
.main,
.sidebar {
    width: 100%;
}
/* all screens 720px wide and above */
@media ( min-width: 720px ) {
    .main {
        width: 65%;
    }
    .sidebar {
        width: 35%;
    }
 }
```

In the end, try to be as fluid as possible to reach the greatest number of device screens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The body will always use the full height and the full width of the browser-windows (viewport).

Answer (score 0):

Try To use something Like this, this will keep screen always full size for any kid of screen

```css
.panel {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;

  &__wrapper {
    padding: 1vh 6vw;
    perspective: 1000px;
  }

  &__content {

    transform-origin: center 80%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="1" class="panel">
      <article class="panel__wrapper">
        <div class="panel__content">
               
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
```

Comment: You should point out that you're not using pure CSS in your example.